# How to print the file names in subdirectories with python glob.glob()

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have a root directory with two subdirectories, cat and dog. In there, I have a few text files. I'm trying to iterate through all the subdirectories and print the file names. Below is the code:

```
import glob
path = '/Users/msmacbook/Desktop/test/'
for x in glob.glob(path+'**/*'):
    print(x.replace(path, ""))
```

And here is the output:

```
cat/cat1
cat/cat2
cat/cat3
dog/dog1
dog/dog2
dog/dog3
```

Where cat and dog are the subdirectories and cat1..etc, dog1..etc are the files.

How do I only print/retrieve the file names? I want the desired output to be

```
cat1
cat2
cat3
dog1
dog2
dog3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just split the path based on the `/` character and print the second (last) element,

```
for x in glob.glob(path+'**/*'):
    x = x.replace(path, "").split('/')
    print(x[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.basename`:

```py
import os
import glob

path = '/Users/msmacbook/Desktop/test/'

for x in glob.glob(path + '**/*'):
    print(os.path.basename(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of the `glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) recommends to use the high-level path objects from the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library. The latter has been around since Python 3.4, released in 2014, and there is no reason not to use it these days.

To only print the file names, but not the full paths, under a given root `folder`, you would do this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('/Users/msmacbook/Desktop/test')
for file in folder.rglob('*'):
    print(file.name)
```